# How do I set up selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

So I have just started learning python and I have decided to play around with selenium, but after installing it, and copy-pasting some very simple code from the pypi.org I was met with a very long error message.

The code I'm trying to run is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://example.com/')
```

I have done "pip install selenium" in cmd and have firefox downloaded but the problem persists.

Comment: Could you provide the mentioned error-message? Otherwise its a bid hard to tell what might cause it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download firefox [webdriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) too.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox('downloaded_driver_path')
browser.get('https://example.com/')
```